# Java InputHandler never executes

Tags: java, keylistener

I'm following the video tutorial linked below from youtube to build a 3D java game.

http://www.youtube.com/user/TH3CHERNO#p/c/0FB6A62E3D328423/12/Ivg8IYYdFyk

On the 12th episode we add an InputHandler to support key controls.  Everything on the first 12 episodes works exactly as expected.  For some reason I'm missing something that makes the InputHandler execute, because it is being ignored.  When the keys are pressed nothing happens.

The project currently includes 7 classes so you probably don't want me to paste all of the code to this post.  I'm not sure what to provide to make this easy to troubleshoot.

My question: What is a logical starting point to determine what I've missed?

The code looks exactly the same as the presenter's code.  Something is obviously different, but I have no idea where to look to resolve it.

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that you missed actually adding your `InputHandler` instance as a listener to your Component.

`addKeyListener(inputHandler)`, `addMouseListener(inputHandler)` and such.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I have the following code in the constructor.  Is this wrong?
  input = new InputHandler();
  addKeyListener(input);
  addFocusListener(input);
  addMouseListener(input);
  addMouseMotionListener(input);

Comment: @alockrem If you are referring to the constructor of your main Component, then this seems to be correct. Try adding a `System.out.println("Listener Works!")` or something similar to one of the `InputHandler` methods and try firing that off.

Comment: Thank you again for the quick response.  I have something similar within the keyPressed event and it never executes.  The main Component is called Display and the logic I added earlier is in the public Display() constructor.

Comment: @alockrem Did you try clicking on the `JFrame` to give it focus?

Comment: Brilliant!  I was just returning to tell you about my amazing discovery about clicking the JFrame to give it focus.  Thank you for all of your help.  I will not make this rookie mistake again.

Comment: @alockrem You welcome. You could also have your `Canvas` automatically gaining focus if you call `requestFocus()` on it. You'll have to call it AFTER adding it to the `JFrame` of course.

Comment: In this tutorial the Display class extends Canvas.  Where should I add the requestFocus() code?

Comment: call `requestFocus()` on the instance of your `Display` class AFTER adding it the `JFrame`.

Comment: I'm sure I'm close, but this still is forcing me to click the frame prior to allowing the keys to execute.    Display game = new Display();
  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  frame.add(game);
  game.requestFocus();

Comment: @alockrem you also have to call `setVisible(true)` on the `JFrame` before focus can be assigned to it or its components.

Comment: That was it.  Thank you very much for all of your help.  Have a great evening.